# Is there a reliable way to determine if a chemical system is more suited to be calculated using a multireference method instead of DFT?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

Some time ago I recall hearing a professor say that looking at a DFT result (I don't remember exactly what, a TD-DFT, spin contamination etc...), he could tell that the system was multireferenced.

My question is: do we have anything in a DFT calculation that is indicative of a multireference system?

Comment: I don't have the time to post an answer right now, but there is a paper by Peter Taylor that introduces the idea that if the norm of the $\hat{T}_1$ operator from a coupled cluster calculation (or roughly $a_1$ from CI) is > o.o2 (I think), the system may have multiconfigurational character.

Comment: I note that while the T1 measurement has been used before, many dispute its usefulness and have introduced other such measurements, such as T2 etc.

Comment: @TAR86 Do you have a reference handy? There's at least one Don Truhlar paper where he evaluates a handful of diagnostics, it could be in there too.

Comment: However, $\hat{T}_1, \hat{T}_2, \dots$ cannot come from an SCF-type calculation, they must come from CCSD or CISD, so they aren't useful. I wouldn't be surprised if there is a TD-DFT quantity related to something like number of $(\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y})^2$ elements above some threshold that's useful.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon Unfortunately, I no longer have access to publications. My old group did some work on strong correlation recently, I assume that at least some references are in there. It may also be of interest to OP: http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/chem.201604682 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at the so called FOD (Fermi Occupied Density) analysis by Grimme et al. That is accessible by ORCA 4 very easy and straight forward by specifying "FOD" as a keyword. [1-3]

[image: FOD Plot from ORCA Input Library]
From ORCA Input Library [1]:

> The FOD plot above (plotted with Chemcraft) indicates a significant and delocalized FOD. Multiconfigurational methods should be used to study this molecule and any single-reference result (HF, DFT, MP2, CC should be regarded with suspicion)

---

Via Multiwfn you can access the "local total/dynamic/nondynamic electron correlation function" and "total/dynamic/nondynamic electron correlation index" [4,5].

[image: Local Descriptors of Dynamic and Nondynamic Correlation from [5]]
Visual abstract from [5]. You can see the dynamic and non-dynamic correlation from which you also can see if single reference methods are acceptable or not.

---

[1] [ORCA Input Library, FOD analysis](https://sites.google.com/site/orcainputlibrary/orbital-and-density-analysis/fod-analysis)
[2] [S. Grimme, A. Hansen, *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2015**, *54* (42), 12308-12313](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/anie.201501887)
[3] [C. A. Bauer, A. Hansen, S. Grimme, *Chem. Eur. J.* **2017**, *23* (25), 6150-6164](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/chem.201604682)
[4] [E. Ramos-Cordoba, P. Salvadorc, E. Matito, *Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.* **2016**, *18*, 24015-24023](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C6CP03072F)
[5] [E. Ramos-Cordoba, E. Matito, *J. Chem. Theory Comput.* **2017**, *13* (6), 2705–2711](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.7b00293)

Comment: FOD = fractional occupied density acc. [2]